# SSLHandshakeError certificate verify failed

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets, ssl-certificate, verify, gspread

I am trying to write to a spreadsheet from my windows desktop, using gspread and python.  The following code works on my mac laptop, but when run on the pc, I get a SSLHandshakeError.  I have made sure that the necessary file is available to the program, and have tried creating new projects with no luck, I always get the same error.

Here is the code:

```
#databaseTest.py
import sys
import os
import pyodbc
import json, gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('H:\MyProject-ee653db0fe92.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
print "Authorizing..."
try:
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    input("Done")
except:
    print "SSL error"
    input("Something went wrong")
    gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

And here is the last part of the error I get:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1059, in connect
raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem with connecting to the spreadsheet from the desktop was caused by the network it was connected to.  The laptop was connected to a different network, which allowed it to communicate with the spreadsheet, but the desktop's network had a number of firewalls and security measures that prevented this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and debugging the Google Lib I found out that the reason was that I was using an older version of `httplib2`(0.9.2). When I updated to the most recent (0.14.0) it worked.

If you already install the most recent, make sure that some lib is not installing an older version of `httplib2` inside its dependencies.